# Expand/Collapse - Javascript

Tags: javascript, hyperlink

I have this code for expanding and collapsing a link area, but I want it to open the page with the option to expand the link, instead of it already being expanded, what am I doing wrong here:

CSS:
    
    body { font:10pt Verdana; }
    a { color:green; }
    #content { background-color:#ffffff; width:800px; margin-top:2px; }

JavaScript:

```
function toggle(id) {
var e = document.getElementById(id);

if (e.style.display == 'none')
e.style.display = '';
else
e.style.display = 'none';
}

function toggle2(id, link) {
var e = document.getElementById(id);

if (e.style.display == 'none') {
e.style.display = '';
link.innerHTML = 'Expand';
} else {
e.style.display = 'none';
link.innerHTML = 'Collapse';
}
}

</script>
```

HTML:
    Lady SabO Artist Bio

```
<div id="content">
text goes here!

</div>
```

Comment: Just reverse the state of the element.In the css start with display=none; and then you js should handle a way to display it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to start it hidden with something like display:none or width:0px.  Then add attribute or css to display.  Better yet, create a 'displayed' class and add it to the element with JQuery in the onclick event.